# why does error say rescue_action_locally method is missing when it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm stumped.

I inherited a Rails 2.X app upgraded to a Rails 3.1 app and I'm getting this weird error...

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `rescue_action_locally' for #<AssignmentsController:0x000000042583d0>:
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:362:in `process_exception'
```

And error output is pointing me to line 362 ...

```
    def process_exception(exception)
      authorize
      set_cashier
      if rescue_as_normal
        ret = rescue_action(exception)
      else
        ret = rescue_action_locally(exception)  <--- but why is this exploding?
      end
      if request and request.xhr?
        response.content_type = Mime::JS
      end
      return ret
    end
```

I'm on rbenv and my ruby is 1.9.3-p551

If I function-click this in Rubymine I can see this exist inside action_dispatch/middleware/show_exeptions.rb:80 ... So I know the thing is there.

I have no idea why this is exploding. Any clues appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK that method disappeared in Rails3 so maybe try to track down a Rails2->Rails3 upgrade guide.

Comment: I just googled "rails rescue_action_locally" and that pointed me at apidock.com. I've done 3->4, 4->5, and 5->6 version upgrades by using the release notes. Rails2 was before my time though.

Comment: @muistooshort Wait..I just realized something. How can this method have disappeared if I am looking right at it inside actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/midleware/show_exception.rb line 80?

Comment: Look at line 62: `private`